# Using complex structures with AddEnvironmentVariables

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables, asp.net-core-2.0

## Question

How to handle complex structures, such as arrays, when using the `ConfigurationBuilder`'s `AddEnvironmentVariables` approach for setting config.

i.e. What would the environment variables be called to represent the below structure?

```
{
    "MyApp": {
        "SendAlertsTo": [
            {"Name": "Joe Blogger", "Email": "JoeBlogger@example.com"},
            {"Name": "Jane Doer", "Email": "JaneDoer@example.com"}
        ]
    }
}
```

## Detailed version with context

We're writing apps that will be hosted in containers.  Initially we'd continued to use the `AppSettings.json` file to hold settings, populating this file's contents from environment variables at startup via an `entrypoint.sh` shell script.

We later realised that we could use the `ConfigurationBuilder`'s `AddEnvironmentVariables` method to pull the values directly from the environment variables, and thus avoid the overhead of maintaining the `entrypoint.sh` script as being another place to update each time a new setting was added.

This works well for an app settings file such as:

```
{
    "MyApp": {
        "SmtpServer": "smtp.example.com",
        "FromAddress": "JoeyBlogger@example.com"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": "Default"
    }
}
```

.. as this translates simply to:

```
export MyApp:SmtpServer=smtp.example.com
export MyApp:FromAddress=JoeyBlogger@example.com
export Logging:LogLevel=Default
```

However, I recently saw a developer's app settings file for some new monitoring, which looks like the below (note; this won't be the actual settings used in our hosted environments; it's just an example which triggered this question). In this case, using the above approach doesn't work so well, since there would be two different settings with the name `Serilog:WriteTo:Name`, and ambiguity over which entry anything starting `Serilog:WriteTo:Args:*` relates to.

```
{
  "Serilog"
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "path": ".\\log.txt",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 7,
                "buffered": true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My guess is we'd handle this via some sort of index; but I've not been able to find anything in the docs about this.

```
export Serilog:WriteTo[0]:Name=Async
export Serilog:WriteTo[0]:Args:configure[0]:Name=File
export Serilog:WriteTo[0]:Args:configure[0]:Args:path=.\\log.txt
export Serilog:WriteTo[0]:Args:configure[0]:Args:rollingInterval=Day
export Serilog:WriteTo[0]:Args:configure[0]:Args:retainedFileCountLimit=7
export Serilog:WriteTo[0]:Args:configure[0]:Args:buffered=true
export Serilog:WriteTo[1]:Name=Async
export Serilog:WriteTo[1]:Args:configure[0]:Name=Console
```

However, running a quick PoC shows that the above doesn't work.  How can this be done?

Comment: You may change `:` in name to double underscope `__`, it'll work [across all platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: [MS Extensions Configuration Deep Dive](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2018/06/20/microsoft-extensions-configuration-deep-dive/).

The answer is that indexes are used, but the index number is treated like a named element; i.e.

```
{
    "MyApp": {
        "SendAlertsTo": [
            {"Name": "Joe Blogger", "Email": "JoeBlogger@example.com"},
            {"Name": "Jane Doer", "Email": "JaneDoer@example.com"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```
export MyApp:SendAlertsTo:0:Name=Joe Blogger
export MyApp:SendAlertsTo:0:Email=JoeBlogger@example.com
export MyApp:SendAlertsTo:1:Name=Jane Doer
export MyApp:SendAlertsTo:1:Email=JaneDoer@example.com
```

Additionally, for Linux hosting there's another point I'd not been aware of / unrelated to the array question.. the `:` separator should be `__`, so the above becomes:

```
export MyApp__SendAlertsTo__0__Name=Joe Blogger
export MyApp__SendAlertsTo__0__Email=JoeBlogger@example.com
export MyApp__SendAlertsTo__1__Name=Jane Doer
export MyApp__SendAlertsTo__1__Email=JaneDoer@example.com
```